# Get the column type information from CsvProvider?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have the following code to get the type information of a CSV file. How to get the type information of columns? I will need to save it to a database table.

```
open FSharp.Data

type MyFile = CsvProvider<"""C:\temp\sample.csv""">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let myFile = MyFile.Load("""C:\temp\sample.csv""")

    printfn "%A" ((myFile.Rows |> Seq.head).GetType())
    // Write the type information of myFile columns to a table

    for row in myFile.Rows do
        printfn "%A" row
    0
```

The function `((myFile.Rows |> Seq.head).GetType())` returns embedded tuples of basic F# types and the header names are missing.

```
System.Tuple`8[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32
,System.String,System.String,System.Tuple`8[System.Int32,System.String,System.De
cimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Int32,System.Tuple`8[S
ystem.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],Syst
em.String,System.Boolean,System.Int32,System.Tuple`8[System.Decimal,System.Int32
,System.Int32,System.Decimal,System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System
.Int32,System.Tuple`8[System.Decimal,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Null
able`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Decimal,System.Decim
al,System.String,System.Tuple`8[System.String,System.String,System.String,System
.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Tuple`8[System.String,S
ystem.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Null
able`1[System.Int32],System.Tuple`8[System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`
1[System.Int32],System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.T
uple`8[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,Sys
tem.String,System.String,System.Tuple`1[System.String]]]]]]]]]]
```

Expected output,

```
ColumnA int
ColumnB datetime
ColumnC varchar
....
```

Comment: Side note: if you are loading from the same file you provided to the type provider, you can just call `GetSample()` instead of `Load("file name")`

Comment: Great. `GetSample()` is good in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure someone can provide a more idiomatic way to organize this, but this should at least work (note also I am explicitly not doing any exception handling and accessing the value of a `string [] option` value (`Headers`)). Parameters are on new lines for formatting purposes, FYI.:

```
let rec iterateTupleMemberTypes (tupleArgTypes: System.Type[]) 
    (columnNames: string[]) 
    (startingIndex : int) =
    let mutable index = startingIndex
    for t in tupleArgTypes do
        match t.IsGenericType with
        | true -> iterateTupleMemberTypes (t.GetGenericArguments()) columnNames index
        | false ->
            printfn "Name: %s Type: %A" (columnNames.[index]) t
            index <- index + 1
```

And call it like this:

```
let firstRow = MyFile.Rows |> Seq.head
let tupleType = firstRow.GetType()
let tupleArgTypes = tupleType.GetGenericArguments()
iterateTupleMemberTypes tupleArgTypes MyFile.Headers.Value 0
```

The recursive nature of `iterateTupleMemberTypes` is necessary because once your tuple gets to a certain number of "members" the last member is used to stuff all the remaining members in a tuple of its own. In my testing, this happened once I hit 8 members of the tuple.

**EDIT**

OP asked in comments about how to modify `iterateTupleMemberTypes` to build up a collection of type/name pairs, well here that is (I decided to just put them as tuples):

```
let iterateTupleMemberTypes (tupleArgTypes: System.Type[]) (columnNames: string[]) =
    let rec iterateRec (argTypes: System.Type list) (values) (index) =
        match argTypes with
        | [] -> List.rev values
        | head :: tail when head.IsGenericType -> 
            iterateRec (List.ofArray (head.GetGenericArguments())) values index
        | head :: tail -> 
            iterateRec tail ((head, columnNames.[index])::values) (index + 1)
    iterateRec (List.ofArray tupleArgTypes) List.empty 0
```

Call it like this:

```
let tupleType = firstRow.GetType()
let tupleArgTypes = tupleType.GetGenericArguments()
let schemaStuff = iterateTupleMemberTypes tupleArgTypes MyFile.Headers.Value
```

And as an additional bonus method, here's how you can iterate through those resulting tuples:

```
let rec printSchemaMembers (schema:(System.Type*string) list) =
    match schema with
    | (argType, name)::tail ->
        printfn "Type: %A, Name: %s" argType name
        printSchemaMembers tail
    | [] -> ignore
```

Comment: Sounds good. How to update the function `iterateTupleMemberTypes` to return a `dict`/`map` of `ColumnName` and Type?

Comment: I posted an answer to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30590166/2894770
Nesting the tuples starts at 8 columns due to the fact, that there are `System.Tuple`s up to 8 generic arguments.